# Is there any way to simulate IIS 7 URL-rewrite functions during development with Visual Studio.NET 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, url-rewriting

When developing websites for IIS 7 and making use of rewrite functions - those that are written to web.config, like

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Regel 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="([a-zA-Z0-9%äöü\-]*)_([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)_([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]*).htm$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.aspx?s={R:1}&amp;h={R:2}&amp;a={R:3}" />
            </rule>
...
```

-how does one emulate the IIS rewriting engine? Is the only way to set up and test websites in a local IIS (Express) server rather than the integrated ASP.NET development server? Any convenient, simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using IIS Express (or IIS) is the only way.